# Why does this FOR needed to shorten the lenght of the array?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

So i started learning python and decided to do codingbat simultaniously to excercise my coding.
I came upon this warmup which i could finish, but, the solution from them kinda threw me off.

Given an array of ints, return True if the sequence of numbers 1, 2, 3 appears in the array somewhere. (**their solution**)

```
def array123(nums):
  # Note: iterate with length-2, so can use i+1 and i+2 in the loop
  for i in range(len(nums)-2):
    if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
      return True
  return False
```

The note says, *itirate with lenght-2, so can use i+1 and i+2*, which i dont understand why it needs to be shortened?

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
```

This bring the same result on python but in codingbat's compilator i get this error: *list index out of range*. Is it something from their compiler or could this potentially cause me an error when coding something similar? Or is there something im missing?

Appreciate if anyone can make me understand it!

Comment: Let's say your array is length 5.  If you ran `i` from 0 to 4, the full length, in the last iteration you would be referencing `nums[4]`, `nums[5]`, and `nums[6]`, and both 5 and 6 will cause IndexError.

Comment: To see the error, you need to test with an array that has a `1` near the end (in the last two values). If there's no `1` there, the `and` checks will short-circuit and you won't get the `IndexError`.

Comment: thanks! didnt check it that way, now i understand my confusion!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that if `i` becomes `len(nums)-1` or larger, then the `nums[i+1]` and `nums[i+2]` values that you check for will be off the end of the list.

You may not see the error for all inputs though, because your function won't check those values every time. First of all, if the pattern `1, 2, 3` is found earlier in the list, then it will `return True` early and won't ever get to the end. Even if you do get to the last few values of `i`, your code won't check off the end if the first value you check, `nums[i]` is not `1`, because the `and` operator short-circuits (meaning, it doesn't test its right hand side if the left hand side is falsey). Similarly, it won't check `nums[i+2]` unless `nums[i+1]` isn't `2`.

To see the error that the site you're submitting to is getting, try testing your code with an input like `[0,0,0,1]` or `[0,0,1,2]`. You'll get the same index error. If you iterate only on `i` values less than `len(nums)-2`, you won't get an error, even with those inputs.

Comment: got it thanks! After reading everyones input i noticed what i was not clearly seeing, i tried putting the sequence unfinished at the last and indeed got the error on python. Learned something new today